# Extract contents of line from file given the line number in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl, string-matching

I know this question has been asked in the context of perl and grep, but I'm wondering if this is possible using TCL.

Currently I'm using the scanmatch command to find a particular regex in a text file. I see that the array element matchInfo(linenum) provides the line number of the matched line. Given this line number as an index, I want to extract contents of subsequence lines.

I'm wondering if there is a function that allows line contents to be extracted by line number.

For reference, I am following this page [http://www.ucolick.org/~de/book/scan.html](http://www.ucolick.org/%7Ede/book/scan.html)

Thanks!

Comment: To [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should provide some sample code, some sample input, and clearly describe what output you wish to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

A read through that page indicates `matchinfo(offset)` would be most appropriate.

If you have

```
scanmatch $scanContext "some pattern" {nextLines 5 $fileName $matchinfo(offset)}
```

So `nextLines` could perhaps return the next *number* of lines. The magic here is the `seek` command to jump right to the line that matched.

```
proc nextLines {numLines fileName offset} {
    set fid [open $fileName r]
    seek $fid $offset
    for {set i 0} {$i < $numLines} {incr i} {
        if {[gets $fid line] == -1} break
        lappend lines $line
    }
    close $fid
    return $lines
}
```

You could experiment by passing `$matchinfo(handle)` instead of the filename, and reading the next few lines directly (without having to seek). However I don't know how scanfile will react if the position into the file is changed by some other code.

---

Just did some quick experimentation, and scanfile is not bothered if you read ahead in the scanmatch code. scanfile will pick up at the new location in the file. This would be similar to using `getline` in awk code.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helps! Would you happen to know how to do this without using the scanmatch command? I just realized that I'm not able to install the tclx library onto the linux server at work.

Comment: You'll do the bulk of the work in a `while {[gets $filehandle line] != -1} {...}` loop. There will be a series of `if {[regexp {pattern} $line]} {...}` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't intend to necropost, but `scanmatch` & friends can be easily approximated or re-implemented at the script level. By studying the [TclX sources](https://github.com/flightaware/tclx/blob/5c19ee9d60c2e6cf18b13589a665817b836373ef/generic/tclXfilescan.c#L615), I arrived at a first approximation to process one match:

```
proc scanMatchOnce {filePath pattern handler} {
  set ch [open $filePath r] 
  try {
    while {1} {
      set offset [chan tell $ch]
      if {[chan gets $ch line] < 0 || [eof $ch]} {
        break
      } elseif {[regexp $pattern $line]} {
        apply [list {linestart lineend fileName} $handler ::] $offset [chan tell $ch] $filePath
        break
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }
  } finally {
    catch {chan close $ch}
  }
  return
}
```

This can be easily extended to provide for a scan context, a chain of scan matches etc. Key to the implementation is to use [`chan tell`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm#M42) early enough to capture the offset at which a line starts etc.

The implementation is not meant to provide compat with TclX's scan utilities.

---

Use it along with glenn's example like:

```
scanMatchOnce $someFilePath {some Pattern} {puts [nextLines 5 $fileName $linestart]}
```